# Azure Web App for Containers networking VNET

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm exploring Azure but unable to figure out how to allow my App service to connect to the VNET I created so it can access the HDInsight cluster.

My scenario is this, I'm running a Kafka HDInsight cluster deployed in the VNET I created and I need to also deploy my Azure Web App for Container in the same VNET so it can connect to the Kafka brokers.

I haven't seen a good documentation on this, need help on how to set the Azure app service to connect to my VNET over a private network?

The Network is disabled (don't know why) on my App service.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VNET integration is not available yet for Web App for Containers or App service on Linux. Please follow the UserVoice request for updates on when it will be supported. 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/32534479--linux-enable-vnet-integration-for-app-service-on

Comment: Support has been added since this answer was written.

Comment: The author didn't specify which OS container he needed. Network integration is still unavailable for Windows Containers.