# How can I reach the private IP address of an Azure VM from the container which is inside a Web App (both of the resources are on the same VNet)?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-web-app-for-containers

In Azure I have the following resources: A VM and a Linux Web App for container. After putting them on the same VNet, the started Container within the App Service can't communicate through private IP.

I wanted to include sshd for the container for debugging purposes, however I couldn't connect to the container after connecting the Web App to the VNet (that already has the VM on it).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you still need to configure VNET integration for your Web App?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet
And also read here a bit:
[Azure Web App for Containers networking VNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068775/azure-web-app-for-containers-networking-vnet)

Comment: It has already been integrated with the Web App. Interestingly, from Kudu (bash) with a curl command and the "private-ip:port/path" in the parameter I get the content of the page on the given url but not from the container. Like the Web App knows the private IP of the VM but the container not...?

Comment: Ah interesting. Sounds like a configuration option, or a bug. Sorry got nothing extra to troubleshoot that. Did you make a support ticket in advance? I couldn't actually find anything on the topic of accessing a container through SSH on the App Service.

Comment: Did you try accessing the Webapp VM itself on the IP and then trying the docker commands?